# Using Excel, is there a way to check two SS for the same element info?

Tags: microsoft-excel

For example what I'm doing is seeing if there are duplicate WORKORDER NUMBERS in two different spreadsheets.

What I'm doing now is copying a WO # from one worksheet and selecting FIND on the other to see if it's present, but there are thousands to search through:(

I need to create a third spreadsheet with the Employee #'s that aren't duplicates.

Comment: Please [edit] you post to include clarification and some idea how the data is laid out. The title is a little confusing. Also, only ask one question at a time. Here you are discussing SS, work order numbers and employee number duplicates. Which do you need help with?

Comment: Is this static data, or will it change/update over time requiring you to redo this process? Where does the data come from, a database, manually input, exported from program? Also, which version of Excel are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Assume your work order numbers are in `column A` and `B` of the same work sheet , from `cell 1` down to `cell 100`.

Use `VLOOKUP` like this:

In `C1` type this `formula =VLOOKUP(A1,B$1:B$8,1,FALSE)` and then copy it down to `C100`. You can then filter `column C` to NOT contain `#N/A`.

This will quickly show you which are duplicates. The formula can easily be adapted to work over different sheets.

There is probably a better way to do so using VBA, but this solution will work fine.